# GNU Make: How to run make to a different directory will all given options

Tags: makefile, build

Assume that I have a the following directory structure:

`MyApplication
    Module_A
        mylib.c
    Module_B
        main.c
        more.c
    Configuration
        Config1
            Makefile
        Config2
            Makefile`

When launch `make` in `MyApplication` directory with whatever target and whatever options, I would like it to be run in `MyApplication/Configuration/Conig1`  directory rather than the top directory. How can I make this happen without hardcoding the targets  in the top level Makefile ?

Comment: I think answer to your question is `non-recursive makefiles`. You can use my library about which you can read here: https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md

Comment: Use `Make -C MyApplication/Configuration/Conig1`

Comment: @gaurav I dont want to type that long line everytime I want to compile. The requirement is that I just type make, or say make -j6 and it should run in the specified subdir

Comment: @JayAurabind What about defining a bash function like `mymake() { make -C MyApplication/Configuration/Config1 $*; }`?

Comment: This seems to be the best option yet, writing a bash shell script which would invoke the right build command after reading the default configuration from a file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a makefile in MyApplication/Makefile as so:

```
CONFIG?=Config1
include Configuration/$(CONFIG)
```

If you want to build config1, you can either type `make` or `make CONFIG=Config1`.  If you want to build config2, you type `make CONFIG=Config2`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This takes care of building a different configuration, but does it pass all the options like the target and `-j`  as well ?

Comment: Yes.  This is not a recursive call to make.  Instead, it simply includes the config makefile (expands it inline into the current makefile) before running.   Thus all environment variables, command line options, etc, are preserved.